# Visual Studio 2015 Azure AD and ADFS authentication to Web Server hosted web app

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, owin, wif, adfs

I have a MVC web application hosted in IIS and users are stored in Azure AD. 
I need to authenticate Azure AD users to access web application.
I am using ADFS for this and installation has been done on Azure.

To authenticate I need to know whether I should go for Window Identity Foundation or OWIN?

In many articles i read WIF has been deprecated and Using OWIN. 
Let me know if owin is proper way for my scenario and if some proper examples are available? 
Latest version of WIF is 4.5 which is also not available for VS2015
I understood is WS-FED is using SAML Token for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusion - your MVC application authenticates using Azure AD. Where does ADFS fit in? Have you got a federated tenant?

WIF is still around - people still use it. In VS2015, WIF is built in to .NET. So you can use it.

Yes - WIF (WS-Fed) uses a SAML token.

With OWIN you have a choice - you can use WS-Fed or OpenID Connect (OIDC) or even both.

Unless you are using ADFS 4.0, you need WIF as there is no support for OIDC in the earlier versions.

Comment: ADFS is in azure only. Also can you provide me any sample code. I am using OWIN because microsoft is giving support too and i want to WS-Fed.

Comment: ADFS in Azure is running as a VM. It's not a native Azure component.

Comment: This may help - www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/